# On start change event in dat.gui

Tags: javascript, events, dat.gui

There seem to be no `onStartChange` event in [dat.gui](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui), is there a simple workaround?

Comment: Did my answer help? Or do you have a problem with dat.GUI's onChange event?

Comment: I knew about the onChange event, I was asking if there were a specific event fired only at the beginning of the change (actually, it was more a feature request I guess...).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [onChange](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/master/API.md#controlleronchangefnc--controller) event. This is fired at the start of a change.

Answer (score 0):

If you are moving a scroller the onChange will update as the change is occurring.  If you want it to only update after all changes then use .onFinishChange, here is an example below using onChange.

```
gui.add(options, "distance").min(1).max(300).step(1)
  .onChange(
    function(){
      yourVar = this.getValue();
    }
  )
```

The api docs are now located here [onChange](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/master/API.md#Controller+onChange)